# Instantaneous keyboard state in Linux

Tags: c, linux, input, keyboard

Linux - is there a way to find the instantaneous keyboard state? e.g. is the Enter key currently pressed v. has the Enter key been pressed. I'm trying to process a power-off interrupt on the iMX6 processor - get the interrupt (in user space...), wait 500 or 1000 mS, and check if the key is still pressed. input.c does not seem to have a like-named method. 
Thanks.

Comment: C does not support _methods_ anyway. Anyway: maybe you should implement that in the driver itself?

Answer (score 1):

It might take a bit of effort on your part, but you can query key states and listen for key press-release events by using the [evdev](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) kernel interface.

For an example of how to do this look at [evtest](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest).

Or look at my python re-write: https://github.com/naedanger/pyevtest

I've used both of these tools on an iMX28 platform to listen for key-presses from a simple matrix keypad.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. As it turns out, the hardware was completely uncooperative. The control bits for the alleged interrupt were inoperative, the interrupt worked, but not in the way described in the docs, and it was just an exercise in futility. Ended up writing a simpler keyboard monitor to capture the right key, wait a bit, and determine whether the key was still depressed.